# Name of free VoIP service provider and Is SIP and app to app calling are same?

Tags: android, sip, voip, phone-call, voip-android

Actually, these days I'm working on **app-to-app** calling application and i was looking for `free VoIP` service then i found `onSIP`. It provides us SIP-to-SIP unlimited call for free so my question is **app-to-app** calling and **SIP calling** are same?

If no, there is any other **free Voip** service available in market?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A huge majority of *free VoIP* services are so called: *sip to sip* or *app to app*. Otherwise your question is not enough precise to be answered? Of course, connecting, with SIP, to PSTN is usually not free because there is a cost on pstn side...

Comment: is app to app or sdk to sdk or peer to peer is same ?